# How to instal CKEditor Version 4.2 to YII

Tags: php, yii, ckeditor

How to instal CKEditor Version 4.2 to YII framwork?

Istructions like this: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ckeditor-integration/ don't work because there is no ckeditor.php file in 4.2 version. If i use this instructions i have this error:

> include(CKEditor.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory

So i'll repeat my question again:
How to instal CKEditor Version 4.2 to YII framwork?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that CKEditor is not included in this extension, You can Download CKEditor form its official site and use it with this extension in your applications.

Answer (score -1):

Why especially `CKEditor Version 4.2` ? Random question.

If you can use other rich texts editor, then I would like to suggest [**tinyMCE**](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Following code I am using to implement tinyMCE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "ta1",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",
    inlinepopups_skin: "themepixels",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,outdent,indent,blockquote,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,image,help,code,|,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,removeformat,|,charmap,media,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    skin : "themepixels",

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "<?php echo $this->module->assetsUrl; ?>/css/plugins/tinymce.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
    }
});
</script>
```

Follow the link for more details.

Comment: 4.2 is the latest version of Ckeditor. I decided to use it cause i like it.  TinyMCE is good too.